# Access Rendered HTML from action in console app without making a web request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the rendered HTML my action in my console app, without making a web request.

I have a solution with (for simplicity sake) two projects in it. One is a Console App. One is an MVC4 project.

I have a reference to my MVC app from my console app.

I want to be able to create a new instance of my MVC controller in my console app and say something like:

```
var controller = new MyController();
var model = new MyModel();
var result = controller.GetHelloWorld(model);

var html = ?? // result.ToHtml();
```

I would like `html` to contain the rendered HTML that was returned from the action.

Is this possible?

Comment: Assuming `GetHelloWorld` action returns a `ViewResult`, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string/484932#484932

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but unfortunately because I'm calling it from a scheduled task the viewContext.HttpContext is null, so I can't use that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Razor templating engine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) to render the HTML result.

This example is from the official project codeplex page:

```
  string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
  string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I'm looking for, but I'd prefer not to add that component to my solution just to get this one piece of functionality working. It would be cool if it was part of the normal Razor View engine.